# Error message comes when trying to view template using controller

Tags: laravel, class, view, controller

I am new to laravel and use the laravel 9.37v version. I have the following error message.
I created a blade template. I could view that blade template using view but after I tried to view that template using the controller I got this error message.

`Target class [PagerConntroller] does not exist`

Comment: It seems like there is a spelling error in your Controller. Can you please add the Controller code and the route code related to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the spelling, if it is correct try to import the controller class in the Route. Im assuming the controller name is `PagerConntroller` and the function that you need to call is `index` so your web.php or api.php should be like :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagerConntroller;


Route::get('view',[PagerConntroller::class, 'index']);
```

Or else you can use the controllers without importing by simply uncommenting the namespace variable inside `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` `line:29` the variable will look like  `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` then your route file should be like

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('view','PagerConntroller@index');
```

If you tried both the ways and still the error persists kindly check your class name and the namespace as well